# How can I push a MJPEG stream(from an IP camera) and plus iPhone's audio to RTMP server?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently, I'm in a iOS project which require to capture a MJPEG from IP camera. (Camera capture images from a microscope. According to camera supplier, this camera is transmitting MJPEG data through HTTP stream. I can get the stream through a URL like this, http://192.168.1.156:8196/?action=stream.)

1. I need to display stream on iPhone. This is done by using NSURLSession to parse this stream. Code is like below.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([[self.imageData contentTypeForImageData] isEqualToString:@"image/jpeg"]) {
            UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
            [self saveNewImageToImages:newImage];
        }
        [self refreshImageView];
        self.imageData = [NSMutableData new];
    });
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.imageData appendData:data];
    });
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%s - %@", __FUNCTION__, [NSThread currentThread]);
    NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

2. I need to push these Images together with audio from iPhone to and RTMP server, for live stream.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLg94.png)

Comment: " I need to push these Images together with audio from iPhone to and RTMP server" And what's the doc of the RTMP server? And how is managed the audio on your code?

Comment: Re-encode your image in h264, sound to aac or mp3, pack to flv container and then push it to RTMP, using rtmplib or something like.

Comment: @bukkojot do you have any idea how can I re-encode images in h264, and pack it to flv? Is there any sample code. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: No, since I have no IOS experience at all. In Android world I can use ffmpeg for this purpose and rtmplib already integrated in it.

Comment: @bukkojot This project also need to be implement in Android too later. For ffmpeg, can you can you show me some light? Thanks.

Comment: Just see docs to ffmpeg, it has good examples. You need build library, link statically and supply .so file with all logic.